# Why is my static route not working?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, pfsense

I have a Linux host with two network interfaces between a Windows host and a pfSense router. I am attempting to get the Linux host to act as a router. What I've done so far:

1. Enable ip forwarding on Linux host with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
2. Add static route in pfSense `route add -net 192.168.77.0/24 10.0.0.2`

This apparently isn't enough as I am unable to ping 10.0.0.1 from the Windows host. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked _how far_ the packets go? Do the ping requests reach the Linux PC (if they enter one interface, do they exit another), do they reach the pfSense router, do the responses reach the Linux PC again? [Packet capture](https://www.wireshark.org/) tools [are available](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/diagnostics/packetcapture/index.html) for all systems listed.

Comment: Also, is the Linux PC doing NAT in such a way that packets from 192.168.77.0/24 are being natted so the PFSense router is getting a packet back from the NAT IP rather then the original IP?

Comment: @user1686 All I know is that from the Windows PC I can ping 192.168.77.55 and 10.0.0.2 and get a response, but when I try to ping 10.0.0.1 I get nothing.

Comment: @davidgo I have not configured NAT on the Linux PC. I don't see why NAT would be necessary and am not interested in it if it is not.

Comment: What does a traceroute from the Windows PC show?   Using tcpdump on the Linux box may also show you if traffic is traversing it - and if so, if it is in both directions.   Is it possible you have egress filtering preventing traffic originating on an RFC1918 space appearing on your WAN?

Comment: @Chris_F: Right, so I'm asking you to find out more. Use packet capture tools, use firewall logging rules... It could be that the issue is with the Linux box not forwarding traffic, but it could be that it's with the pfSense box receiving it but not responding, and you need to find out which.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things I was missing.

1. Add a new firewall rule in pfSense for source 192.168.77.0/24
2. Go to DNS resolver and add Access Lists for 192.168.77.0/24

I can now access the Internet and ping pfSense. I cannot ping other Windows machines on 10.0.0.0/24 because of Windows default firewall settings blocking ICMP traffic from outside subnets.